# Usage of GoogleApiClient in an app in the background when Play Services are uninstalled

Tags: android, google-play-services

My application uses the Google Maps Android API v2 and uses the FusedLocationProviderApi. The GoogleApiClient may be connected or disconnected due to event in the application. When the application is in the background, it may happen that the client is connected, i.e. location tracking is on. I don't use the location listener, I just use the LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(locationClient) call every now an then (also dependent on application-specific events).

Normally, in an Activity, I would use the GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() method in onResume() to check if they are available. The thinking is: while the app is sent to the background, the user can uninstall/disable updates of Play Services, and when coming back to the application, onResume() performs the check again and can show a dialog if anything is wrong.

In my use case, the location service is used in the background, i.e. not in an Activity/Fragment, and may also be required to work while the app is in the background. However, at this point, the use can uninstall/disable Play Services.

The question: what happens with the GoogleApiClient connection in my application while it is in the background when Play Services are gone? Do I get a call from the ConnectionCallbacks#nConnectionSuspended() method, or maybe should expect a crash and have to handle it somehow, or does it still work (like I can still watch a movie on Linux, even after I remove the file, because the player has a handle to it)?

Comment: IMHO your question is "overkilling" I mean an user mustn't uninstall google play services, so you don't need to worry about it. If the user with a rooted phone wants to kill its phone is free to do so.

Comment: @greywolf82: I think you are wrong. Please take a look here: http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#ensure. On my nexus 6 with Lollipop I can disable Play Services on my non-rooted phone. Also, a user might have them installed and enabled, but in an earlier version, and such updates may be reverted by the user. So it is not a question of a rooted phone, every user can do this. Sure, disabling them shows a fat warning, but nothing prevents normal users from doing so. Which makes in possible, and I think I should be ready for such scenarios. For Activities it is easy enough

Comment: I didn't say you don't need to do a check. But as the docs says, a check in onResume() of the *main activity* is enough.

Comment: This won't work here. As I said, my connection stays on when the application is in the background, at which point Play Services might be removed. At this point, suddenly, the connection in the background is broken and it all may happen before the next onResume() is ever called. I use the Play Services check in other Activities without issues, it's just this single use case is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to answer my own question: first, ConnectionCallbacks#onConnectionSuspended() is called, followed by OnConnectionFailedListener#onConnectionFailed(). So, when the code which makes use of the services is guarded by a GoogleApiClient#isConnected() call (at least I did it this way), nothing crashes.